# How to make the text alone disappear using CSS upon moving the pointer away

Tags: html, css

[image: Problamatic Animation]

I'm trying to show the text "Follow me" upon hovering.
The text shows up fine but upon moving the mouse pointer away, the text collapses and disappears.

Is there a way to hide the text immediately when moving the pointer away?

Here is my HTML and CSS showing how I'm achieving the current effect:

```css
.fa {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all ease 0.4s;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.fa-google {
  background: #DD4B39;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0pt;
}

.fa-google::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  right: 0.6rem;
  content: "Follow Me";
  transition: all ease 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.fa-google:hover {
  padding: 20px 130px 20px 20px;
}

.fa-google:hover::after {
  right: 1.2rem;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="page" class="container">
  <div class="socialMedia">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-github"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no CSS selector to indicate that the mouse moved away, but you can think about it the other way: there should be no visible text, and it only appears on :hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the transition to the hover definition for the `::after` element. The transition will apply only on hover, and when you'll move the cursor the `::after` will disappear without immediately.

```
.fa-google:hover::after {
  right: 1.2rem;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all ease 0.4s;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
.fa {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all ease 0.4s;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.fa-google {
  background: #DD4B39;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0pt;
}

.fa-google::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  right: 0.6rem;
  content: "Follow Me";
  opacity: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.fa-google:hover {
  padding: 20px 130px 20px 20px;
}

.fa-google:hover::after {
  right: 1.2rem;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all ease 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="page" class="container">
  <div class="socialMedia">
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/+DivakarRajesh" class="fa fa-google"></a>
    <a href="https://mobile.twitter.com/DivakarRajeshS" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/sdivakarrajesh/" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
    <a href="https://github.com/sdivakarrajesh" class="fa fa-github"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```